# Reading and sending e-mails from the Mail app in Windows 10

Tags: c#, email, uwp

I am making a Windows 10 application in which i want to access all the mails from the Mail App and want to check if a particular mail is read or unread. Also if multiple accounts are logged in the Mail App,then i want to choose which account to access.

I came to know about the EmailConversationReader but i don't know how to instantiate it.

Is there any way to read all the mails which are present in the Mail App ?

Answer (score 0):

> I came to know about the EmailConversationReader but i don't know how to instantiate it.

You can call [EmailStore.GetConversationReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.email.emailstore.getconversationreader.aspx) or [EmailStore.GetConversationReader(EmailQueryOptions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt187194.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to instantiate it.

But in order to get it works,Microsoft must approve your use of them and provision your developer account. For this, You need to talk to your local Microsoft Developer Evangelist and they should be able to get you in touch with the right person to help.

You can refer to [this case in MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/cfeeefa7-d079-4de2-887b-931785f2980a/uwp-how-to-get-access-to-windowsnetworkingvpn-apis?forum=wpdevelop), which has a discussion about limited API.